# Does Role Session Name in AWS assume role have to be unique?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sts

AWS documentation says that role session name is used to uniquely identify a session. So what happens if I have 2 instances of my application running which assume the role with same session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To fully quote the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html#API_AssumeRole_RequestParameters), with emphasis added:

> Use the role session name to uniquely identify a session **when the same role is assumed by different principals or for different reasons.**

The goal is to allow forensics based on CloudTrail logs: if you see something assuming a role, you want to know who/what it is.

As a practical example, whenever you assume a role from the AWS Console, it uses your username as the session name.

If you're assuming a role as part of an application, I think it makes sense to use the application name (but beware that your session name has a 64-byte limit!).